# How do I connect to an internal network SQLSRV database securely with PHP?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How do I connect to an internal network SQLSRV database securely with PHP?

I have read up on this and it might have to do with the error message I get of `Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\IUSR'`

fastcgi.impersonate is set to 1

In the SQL database there is no NT AUTHORITY\IUSR setup BUT before I set one up I want to know if its safe or if that allows anyone to connect using it.

If thats not a secure way of connecting how do I connect securely to my database using PHP?

Current PHP with dummy info:

```
// Server in the this format: <computer>\<instance name> or 
// <server>,<port> when using a non default port number
$server='server\login';
$connectinfo=array("Database"=>"mydatabase");
//connect to DB
$db=sqlsrv_connect($server,$connectinfo);

if($db)
{
echo "Connection established.<br/>";
}
else
{
echo "Connection couldn't be established.<br/>";
die(print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Comment: Barring unknown security issues, it's as secure as the windows login is itself. So, how secure is that login? *(What is the possibility of another person / application attempting to connect to the SQL Server while actually logged in as IUSR?)*

Comment: At default when you add it and give it permissions, is it able to be accessed outside the network without knowing any windows login info?

Comment: No, the account can't be spoofed by an external user. A demonstration (but not proof) is to create the credentials in SQL Server, then remove the IUSR account from the client machine (not sure if you need to remove IIS to do this) and then re-create the IUSR account (possilby by re-installing IIS). The new account (on the same machine and with the same 'name') won't be able to connect to SQL Server. Because it's a new account, even though it looks the same.  Just be careful about other applications, etc, being able to use the IUSR account and so implicitly getting access to your SQL Server.

Comment: I forewent using IUSR since it can lead to some vulnerabilities in network and went with making a new SQL user specifically for my DB.

Comment: What vulnerabilities in the network?  An IUSR account created on one machine ***can't*** spoof another

Comment: I mean allowing anyone to use the account rather than require logins.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Created my own user account in SQL Server 2008 with scope only of the database I am working on.